# Keeping points fixed over a place on an interactive map when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I am creating an interactive map:

https://jsfiddle.net/71hns9b3/2/

that uses an image (No Google API etc.) to mark points. With a Google API you use lat, long coordinates so you don't have to worry when you resize the map. Obviously this can't be done without Google API.

```
#termini {
    top: 37.5%;
    left: 61.8%;
}
```

These two images indicate what I mean:

http://s10.postimg.org/6m4oufudl/Screen_Shot_2016_02_22_at_12_45_51.png

Comment: http://s10.postimg.org/jp4wrg9zd/Screen_Shot_2016_02_22_at_12_45_57.png

Comment: use relative position -- https://jsfiddle.net/mv7de8ks/

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position` property `relative` to your container `div`, and also you need to declare `width` and `height` of the pin in `%`
-Best what can be done in this example

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/71hns9b3/14/)

Comment: Check in the following example, you need to scale the pins also. Other solutions would be to use SVG od PS